# Laggy Slider when used as custom TableCell component

Tags: material-ui

I am using a `Slider` as part of a custom `TableCell` custom component (full [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/oon45nqn7z)):

```
const thWithSlider = () => (
      <th>
        <Slider
          classes={{ container: classes.slider }}
          value={value}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </th>
    );

const cell = <TableCell component={thWithSlider} />
```

The slider is very laggy when the value is changed through a mouse drag (clicks to reposition the thumb do work correctly).

Answer (score 0):

```
<TableCell component="th">
  <Slider classes={{ container: classes.slider }} value={value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
</TableCell>;
```

should work just fine. It's not laggy but the Slider is always interrupted. Not quite sure why though.

Comment: That's the workaround I'm using right now (and mentioned in https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15295#issue-431342389). I'd be interested to know what the actual problem is with my initial approach?